# splash screen is not showing on whole screen on mobile

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I am working on android project in which i am working on splash screen code but splash image is not showing on the whole screen of my mobile my code for activity  is :-

```
public class SplashPresenter extends MvpBasePresenter<SplashView> {

    @Override public void attachView(SplashView view) {
        super.attachView(view);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                launch();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override public void detachView(boolean retainInstance) {
        super.detachView(retainInstance);
    }

    private void launch() {
        String imei = ImeiUtil.getIMEI();

        List<ActivationInfo> infos = ActivationInfo.listAll(ActivationInfo.class);
        if (infos.size() == 1) {
            ActivationInfo info = infos.get(0);
/*
            Log.d("I: ", "I: " + info.getBusinessName());
            Log.d("I: ", "I: " + info.getMobileNumber());
            Log.d("I: ", "I: " + info.getImei());
            Log.d("I: ", "I: " + imei);
            Log.d("I: ", "S: " + info.getStatus());
*/
            if (info.getStatus() == 1 && info.getImei().equalsIgnoreCase(imei)) {
                getView().start(HomeActivity.class);
            } else {
               //getView().start(ActivationActivity.class);
            getView().start(HomeActivity.class);
            }
        } else {
           getView().start(HomeActivity.class);
        //  getView().start(RegisterActivity.class);
        }
    }
```

and xml code is, which i had shown is here

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/splash_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_english"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your res/style.xml and manifest file

Comment: can you provide screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/splash_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_english"
    android:minHeight="1000dp"
    android:minWidth="1000dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting your image to fill the screen, change your android:scaleType to something like fitXY. Relying on minHeight and minWidth and using centerCrop aren't going to cover you very well on multiple device sizes. Better solution, develop images with better sizes or use xml based drawables

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your onCreate method of Activity

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```